# How to solve Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider

Tags: android, react-native

I'm using react-native-document-picker to get file from android device and upload them. I was able to pick a file and upload normally but only from folder inside My File. If I pick a file in others directory, for example, Recent (the one display first when open the Document picker) the app would stop immidiately and display error:

*Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider uri content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:3239 from pid=19089, uid=10372 requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs*

despite it is the same file storaged in My File.
I used react-native-image-crop-picker and was able to pick image in any directory.

Below is the code of my manifest file and document picker function:

---------------AndroidManifest----------------

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<application
  
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyCeZH6swcDYvYWT78RhSAQYbE1m_Gt2VXs"/>
  <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>
```

---------------DocumentPickerFunction----------------

```
  let arrFile: FileUploadParam[] = [];

  let pickFile = async () => {
    
DocumentPicker.pick({
      type: [DocumentPicker.types.allFiles],
    }).then((file: any) => {
      
arrFile.push(
        fileStorageService.createFileUploadParam(file.name, file.uri, false),
      );

      fileStorageService.uploadChatAttachs(arrFile).subscribe((result) => {
        let urlArr: MessageAttach[] = [];
        result.map((item: any) => {
          urlArr.push({
            name: item.name,
            storage_filename: item.storage_filename,
            url: item.url,
            type: AttachType.FILE,
          });
        });

        chatService
          .sendAttachFileMessage('', urlArr, roomId)
          .subscribe((message) => {});
        console.log('Upload data', urlArr);
      });
    });
  };
```

Comment: did you managed to solve this?